# android:paddingLeft set to be percentage of screen

Tags: android, layout, android-linearlayout

I have a textview component that I set its width as 50% of its parent through layout_weight. I also need to set a padding value for it. It seems I can set it as xdp, but how can I use weight config ? say, left padding as 2% of the screen?

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/buttonCollect"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="@string/hello"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"   //<---- how to se this.
        android:layout_weight="0.5" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot set percentage as padding value in XML layout file.

However, you can set it in Java code, by calculating the correct length in px.

Comment: Thanks. if I want to set width as 90% of the parent, while height is 80% of the parent, I set both to 0dp. How should I set the layout_weight? as it seems there is one layout_weight

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dimens.xml` and put them in different `values-xxx` folder. If u want `8dp` in `hdpi` devices, and `10dp` in `hdpi-1024x600`, u can follow these steps:

1. Create `dimens.xml` in `values-hdpi` folder.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <dimen name="paddingLeft">8dp</dimen>
   </resources
   ```
2. Create `dimens.xml` in `values-hdpi-1024x600` folder.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <resources>
       <dimen name="paddingLeft">10dp</dimen>
   </resources
   ```
3. Replace `android:paddingLeft="8dp"` to 
   `android:paddingLeft="@dimen/paddingLeft"`

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a horizontal *LinearLayout* with a *View* and a *TextView* as its children and assign weights accordingly. Then, there is no need to set *padding* to the *TextView*.

Here, the *TextView* takes 2/3rd of the screen.

```
<LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Lagre text"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>
```